# Fix NavigationDrawer scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview, navigation-drawer

I have a problem in handling the scroll of NavigationDrawer. I have 3 listview in it, with 3 headers.
I want that listview could wrap their height to their content so they haven't to be scrolled. Obviously in this way if the last listview couldn't stay entirely in layout, she hasn't to scroll, but has to scroll the linear layout in which they are.
I tried some ways but i didn't fixed it. One of them was to put the linear layout inside a ScrollView but when i tried it, the content of listview was reduced to one line for each.

Here is what i'm obtaining now (without the ScrollView try):

[image]

Here is what i want to obtain with a scroll:

[image]

Here is my XML code (without ScrollView try):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#fff">
       </ListView>

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list2"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#fff">
       </ListView>

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list3"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#fff">
      </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Sorry for the long content of this question but i wanted to do a clear question.

Comment: Is the content dynamic?

Comment: @DorAyalon if you mean the content of the listview (so the list items) it has to be dynamic for some counters on sections. Also the content of the list items has to be dynamic. The only static thing is the number of items inside these listview.

Answer (score 0):

So if the number of rows is static, I would suggest not using listviews.
Use just textview (or whatever you want for each row)
And give the parent layout weight_sum=[number of elements]
For each row give height=0dip, weight=1:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry i thought to this solution but i prefer to use a List for my operations, for a more clean code